# Python For Loops - Enumerate

Tags: loops, for-loop, enumerate

can you help me with this? Tried the below code but doesn't work. I'm trying to print out the attached output. Thanks in advance.

```py
num_display = int(input('Please enter how many numbers you would like displayed: '))
inc_value = int(input('Please enter the increment value: '))
num_counter = 1
num_sequence = range(1, num_display + 1 , inc_value)
value_counter = range(1, num_counter, inc_value)

for each_num in num_sequence:
    print(f'Counter: {num_counter} value: {each_num}')
    num_counter = num_counter + 1
    value_counter = value_counter + 1
print("Bye.")
```

What the output should look like

```
Please enter how many numbers you would like displayed: 12
Please enter the increment value: 3
Counter: 1 value: 1
Counter: 2 value: 4
Counter: 3 value: 7
Counter: 4 value: 10
Counter: 5 value: 13
Counter: 6 value: 16
Counter: 7 value: 19
Counter: 8 value: 22
Counter: 9 value: 25
Counter: 10 value: 28
Counter: 11 value: 31
Counter: 12 value: 34
Bye.
```

I made changes to the code to meet other conditions but I'm getting this error after converting str to int:
line 11, in 
num_sequence = range(1,stop_value,inc_value)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

my code:

```
num_display = input('Please enter how many numbers you would like displayed: ').strip()
inc_value = input('Please enter the increment value: ').strip()
zero_value = 0

if num_display.isdigit() and inc_value.isdigit():
    if int(num_display) != zero_value or int(inc_value) != zero_value:
        stop_value = int(num_display) * int(inc_value)
        num_sequence = range(1,stop_value,inc_value)
        for num_counter, each_num in enumerate(num_sequence):
                        print(f'Counter: {num_counter + 1} value: {each_num}')
        print('Bye.')
    else:
        print("I can't increment in steps of 0.")     

else:
    print('Positive non zero integers only please.')
```

I got it working using the below but it doesn't print the other one correctly, see screenshot:

```
num_display = input('Please enter how many numbers you would like displayed: ').strip()
inc_value = input('Please enter the increment value: ').strip()
zero_value = 0

if num_display.isdigit() and inc_value.isdigit():
    if int(num_display) != zero_value and int(inc_value) != zero_value:
        stop_value = int(num_display) * int(inc_value)
        num_sequence = range(1, int(stop_value), int(inc_value))
        for num_counter, each_num in enumerate(num_sequence):
                        print(f'Counter: {num_counter + 1} value: {each_num}')
        print('Bye.')
    else:
        print("I can't increment in steps of 0.")     

else:
    print('Positive non zero integers only please.')
```

[working but not printing 5 on the other test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoqIC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) does increment the counter by `inc_value` automatically after each iteration, so don't manually update that counter in your loop.

Additionally there is a mathematical problem. If you want to print a number `num_display` times incremented by `inc_value` the formula to calculate the the last number (and hence the `end` value for `range()`) is `start_value + inc_value * num_display`, not `num_display + 1`. In your case the `start_value` is `1`.

To get the number of iterations in a pythonic way use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```py
num_display = int(input('Please enter how many numbers you would like displayed: '))
inc_value = int(input('Please enter the increment value: '))
start_value = 1
num_sequence = range(1, start_value + num_display * inc_value, inc_value)

for num_counter, each_num in enumerate(num_sequence):
    print(f'Counter: {num_counter + 1} value: {each_num}')
print("Bye.")
```

Expected output

```
Please enter how many numbers you would like displayed: 12
Please enter the increment value: 3
Counter: 1 value: 1
Counter: 2 value: 4
Counter: 3 value: 7
Counter: 4 value: 10
Counter: 5 value: 13
Counter: 6 value: 16
Counter: 7 value: 19
Counter: 8 value: 22
Counter: 9 value: 25
Counter: 10 value: 28
Counter: 11 value: 31
Counter: 12 value: 34
Bye.
```

Comment: I made changes to the code to meet other conditions but I'm getting this error after converting the str to int:  line 11, in <module>
    num_sequence = range(1,stop_value,inc_value)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
See above. Thanks.

Comment: The problem you have is actually related to the start value. As I've said the `start_value` is `1` but (and that's where I had a slight mixup in my head) you therfore **cannot** omit it as the `end` value of `range()` is exclusive. I've edited my answer to include that. This is no problem when the step value is greater than `1` but it is a problem if the step value is `1` and that's why it does not work for your second example with `5` and a step value of `1`. Add the `start_value` of one and it works.